# Fetch the user information with the permission into facebook instant game

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-instant-games

Please help me regarding my query.

I make an instant game and into that game i want the user (player) information ( like email, gender,birthday and location).

I use below following code to get the information but not working
here is the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {

        FB.init({
            appId: '<app_id>',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v3.2'
        });

        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

        function onLogin(response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,birthday,gender,installed,email', function (data) {
                    console.log('Hello, ' + data.first_name + '!');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            // Check login status on load, and if the user is
            // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                onLogin(response);
            } else {
                // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    onLogin(response);
                }, {scope: 'email'});
            }
        });
};
```

but when i run this code into the IG then error occurred-
The operation is insecure.

Please help me provide a solution that can i fetch the user information with the permission.

here the below following steps:

a) on Facebook developer account create an app

b) then add product Facebook login

c) and  also app center - here add the permission that want to ask from user.

d) after that open the application page where the below

[App url https://www.facebook.com/games/app_namespace : show these permisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1vzl.jpg)

Comment: did the user actually authorize your app with the correct permissions?

Comment: yes, when user play my game then i ask for that permission on the application page, but on the game play then i m not able to fetch that information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Facebook login SDK inside Instant Games. You must use the relevant FBInstant methods (e.g. `FBInstant.player.getName()`) to get player information. It is currently not possible to access the player’s email address and gender from within Instant Games.

Comment: is there any way into game to add a link of the external url related to game url of facebook. : https://www.facebook.com/games/demo-game

Comment: There is not, Instant Games is a separate product and not integrated with web games.